# For loop in bash via ssh for parallel network

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, for

I have 4 CPUs in a parallel network and want to run N jobs on each of those 4 CPUs. I also want to divide N number of jobs into X jobs and run that as a loop on each of the 4 CPUs. The bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
runevents() {
   nEvents=5000
   nJobs=100
   ePerJob=$((nEvents/nJobs))
   ssh $1
   for ((i=0; i<nJobs; i++))
   do
      dir_run=/home/user/task/
      "cd $dir_run && nice -n0 ./commandscript -c commandscipt.cmnd -o results/job_$RANDOM -s $RANDOM -n $ePerJob >$dir_run/job_$RANDOM.out"
   done
}

runevents cpu1
runevents cpu2 
runevents cpu3
runevents cpu4

exit
```

But this does not work as intended. It gives the error that the file or path does not exist, which exists and the paths are correct. Also if I modify the line to:

`ssh $1 "cd $dir_run && nice -n0 ./commandscript -c commandscipt.cmnd -o results/job_$RANDOM -s $RANDOM -n $ePerJob >$dir_run/job_$RANDOM.out"`
It works but then asks for the password as many times as nJobs which is a ridiculous method. I have used ssh-keygen in the remote machine, say cpu1 (also part of the parallel nework) where I compile the `commandscript.cc` to generate a keypair by `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, the private key is stored in `id_rsa` and in `authorized_keys`, the public keys are stored in `id_rsa.pub` and also in `authorized_keys.pub`.
Any insight into fixing this situation? I don't have sudo access to the parallel network.

Comment: Show the error message, don't describe it. And show how you will run the script.

Comment: Have you ran the script through `shellcheck`?

Comment: You have no command or address (I don't know what is in `$1`) for `ssh`.

Comment: Your script is not running the `for` loop over ssh; it's running `ssh` with no remote command at all, and then after that finishes it's trying to run the `for` loop locally. And the command in the `for` loop fails because it's quoted (and running on the wrong computer).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the command is ```./commandscript```. For ```$1```, I think it takes the name of CPUs as the argument. It works fine even without ```-f```flag, I think it is a typo that I made previously.

Comment: I read again and see that the `$1` is in a procedure. So on first call it is `cpu1`, however there is no command. Therefore `ssh` will login interactively., but that contradicts `-f` so you should get an error-message `cannot fork into background without a command to execute.`

Comment: and that `cd` line is dodgy. Did you run it through `shellcheck`? After doing that then tell us what the error message is.

Comment: Oh and my questions, they are not because I don't know. If you answer them, then you will gain understanding.

Comment: If put double quotes around $1, shellcheck says that no issues are detected in the above code.

Comment: cd actually directs to the directory where the files are residing, so whenever it ssh-es into a CPU that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

> asks for the password as many times as nJobs which is a ridiculous method.

Make yourself an ssh-keypair (with `ssh-keygen`), use `ssh`/`scp` to login as the user you have rights for onto the remote computer and store the public key of the pair inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. No `sudo` needed.

> But this does not work as intended. [...] if I modify the line to:

You've fixed this problem yourself.

Also have a look at [parellel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) with a list of remote hosts. Might save you a bit of script-writing.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, but even though the ssh keys are saved in the ```~/.ssh/authorized_keys``` it still asks for the password.

Comment: Which `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? (on which machine)

Comment: file permissions for the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are very important. `chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  ~/.ssh`

Comment: You can debug the key issue directly with `ssh`, without your script. Use `ssh -v` for details what the client thinks it is doing, and why the key is not accepted. And please include this information ("I have used ssh-keygen in the following way to generate a keypair, the private key is stored in ..., the public keys are stored in") in the question in the future - we can't guess that.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ```~/.ssh/authorized_keys``` on the remote machine where I am first compiling my file ```commandscript.cc``` and then running it via the bash script that I shared in the question. I am also sshing into other systems in the same network as the remote.